# CultureInfo.NumberFormat no aplica bien los formatos en algunos idiomas

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estoy desarrollando una función que, pasandole un número, lo formatee con los separadores de los miles y los separadores de los decimales (si los tiene) teniendo en cuenta la información cultural del usuario en cuestión, y se me plantea el siguiente problema:

Tengo esta porción de código:

```
public string FormatearNumero(object Num)
{
    CultureInfo Culture = new CultureInfo("en-EN", false);
    NumberStyles NStyle = NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowThousands | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign;

    string Numero = Num.ToString();

    if (decimal.TryParse(Numero, NStyle, Culture, out decimal result))
    {
        if (result == 0)
            return Numero;

        Numero = result.ToString("###" + Culture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator + "###" + Culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator + "####", Culture);
    }
    return Numero;
}
```

Para formatar el número uso el típico `.ToString("###.###,###")` pero en este caso aplicando en los separadores de miles el que le toca por referencia cultural y lo mismo por el separador de decimales.

```
result.ToString("###" + Culture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator + "###" + Culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator + "####", Dades.Culture)
```

Aplicando esta porción de código con cultura `en-EN` obtengo los siguientes resultados:

```
//Culture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator tiene el valor ','
//Culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator tiene el valor '.'

FormatearNumero("-98745618451.6513") --> "-98,745,618,451.6513"
```

En cambio, cuando le cambio la referencia cultural y le pongo, por ejemplo, `es-ES` pasa lo siguiente:

```
//Culture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator tiene el valor '.'
//Culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator tiene el valor ','
FormatearNumero("-98745618451,6513") --> "-98745618451,6513"
```

No me aplica correctamente los formatos para algunas culturas, pero para otras si.

He intentado buscar información al respecto pero no he encontrado nada, y en las páginas de `Microsoft` no indican nada a tener en cuenta a la hora de aplicar estos formatos.

¿Alguien sabria decirme dónde puede estar el problema?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es problema que tienes es con el formato personalizado que estas utilizando. Asumiste que en el formato tenías que poner el separador que correspondía a la cultura elegida (por ejemplo, `.` como separador de miles en español, `,` como separador de miles en inglés).

Tal y como se explica en [Cadenas con formato numérico personalizado](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings), el `.` en el formato siempre actúa como separador decimal, y la `,` siempre como separador de grupos:

> El especificador de formato personalizado "." inserta un separador
>   decimal localizado en la cadena del resultado. El primer punto de la
>   cadena de formato determina la ubicación del separador decimal en el
>   valor con formato y se omite cualquier punto adicional. El carácter
>   que se usa como separador decimal en la cadena de resultado no es
>   siempre un punto; viene determinado por la propiedad
>   NumberDecimalSeparator del objeto NumberFormatInfo que controla la
>   aplicación de formato.

Es decir, en el formato siempre debes usar los mismos caracteres como separador de grupos y decimal. Luego es la cultura que usas al formatear el número la que indicará si en la salida el separador es uno u otro.

Resumiendo, tu cadena de formato debería ser la siguiente sin importar la cultura que vas a usar: `"###,###.####"`. De esa manera te lo formateará correctamente independientemente de la cultura utilizada:

```
Numero = result.ToString("###,###.####", Culture);

//Con cultura en-EN
FormatearNumero("-98745618451.6513") -> -98,745,618,451.6513
//Con cultura es-ES
FormatearNumero("-98745618451,6513"); -> -98.745.618.451,6513
```